# google-assistant-sdk returns "give me the permission to help you"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have integrated the sdk to my app and it worked fine for months, but since to day no matter what I asked, it simply returns "give me permission to help you", so any one knows how to deal with this?

More details: according to the log, the server has recognized what I say, so I think this may not casued by some kind of accessed permission.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue. On the [Activity Controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) page, make sure to enable:

1. **Web & App Activity** and also check: *"Include Chrome browsing history and activity..."*.
2. **Device Information**
3. **Voice & Audio Activity**

Answer (score 0):

This may require an extra step for business users, who have to turn on "Web & App Activity" for the organisation first at [this address](https://admin.google.com/ac/appslist/additional) (and then wait 24 hours)